# Catch all exception in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a Unity mobile game in the app stores and I've got a function that sends emails from the players to my server, to notify me that stuff happened, that is not supposed to happen. If e.g. a `try` that I wrote fails, I send myself an email to see, that there must be a bug.

Is it possible, to build something like an OnException handler, that sends me an email on every exception that occurs, including code I didn't write? Some exceptions may come from plugins that I use, so I would like to have some sort of Listener, that does stuff whenever any sort of exception get's called.

Is that possible?

Comment: I think it might be possible. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You **can't** catch all other exceptions in other plugins. Unity does that in the background and Unity gives you API to receive the exceptions it caught:

**Newer version of Unity**:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived += LogCallback;
}

//Called when there is an exception
void LogCallback(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    //Send Email
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived -= LogCallback;
}
```

**Older version of Unity**:

```
void OnEnable()
 {
     Application.RegisterLogCallback(LogCallback);
 }

 //Called when there is an exception
 void LogCallback(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
 {
     //Send Email
 }

 void OnDisable()
 {
     Application.RegisterLogCallback(null);
 }
```

There is also [`logMessageReceivedThreaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceivedThreaded.html).

**EDIT**:

**Stacktrace issue**:

If the `stackTrace` parameter is empty then you can use the `System.Diagnostics.StackTrace` class to manually retrieve the stacktrace yourself while still inside the `LogCallback` function. For example,

```
void LogCallback(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    //Send Email

    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace sTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
    Debug.Log(sTrace.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That's pretty straight forward, if it works. I'm gonna test it asap.

Comment: When I switch to Unity Pro in the future, this becomes basically redundant, as Unity Performance Reporting does this for me, doesn't it?

Comment: You don't need this if you have Pro since this is in `Unity Performance Reporting`. Note that some companies use their server to report errors with the code above even though they could have used `Unity Performance Reporting`. When you use `Unity Performance Reporting`, you are depending on Unity's server. If their server is down, you are screwed. I've seen their server go down once just like the Amazon server went down  once. You should always make your app/game not dependent on other companies' server.

Comment: So do I understand this correctly: I have to add this lines of code to every(!) MonoBehaviour?

Comment: @cagcoach No that script would just be on a gameobject (maybe called something like "logCatcher" or whatever) and then that gameobject/script would do something with the exceptions (maybe display something to the user, maybe just log it in a file, maybe send it to the dev). All you're doing is registering that you'd like your custom function to be called when there's a new log message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, should work for your case:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/47659/callback-for-unhandled-exceptions.html

Comment: No, the solution given there is now deprecated. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hockey App](https://hockeyapp.net/). Really nice tool, has Unity sdk and does exactly what you need. Every Debug.LogError or Debug.LogException is getting reported there. So you can be notified not only about code exceptions but also some data missing or anything you would like to report as error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer a question that was marked as a duplicate to this one ( [How to detect if there is an error in unity c# when running without see the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341179/how-to-detect-if-there-is-an-error-in-unity-c-sharp-when-running-without-see-the) ), however it's been closed, so i'm adding an answer here.

I wanted to print a message directly to the screen as using the debug log wasn't going to work in my case. This was the elegant solution I found (which uses Android's default ShowDialog):

```
using (AndroidJavaClass androidJavaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.cattlecall.unityandroidaccessor.UnityAndroidDialog"))
{
    androidJavaClass.CallStatic("ShowDialog", new object[]
    {
        "PORT",
        port.ToString(),
        "yis'm",
        "NOOOOO"
    });
}
```