# How to detect if there is an error in unity c# when running without see the console?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to detect an error in a C# script running in Unity without reading the console log ?
I need this when I have to build the game and test it in a mobile. If there is an error when running it will display a message box that shows the error.

I understand that we can use Unity Log Viewer to print all the Log in the device. But I ask for another way to do this. I ask a simpler solution. My solution I think it is a best to detect a minor errors when it runs successfully in editor, but has problems when running in a device due it just displays a showMessageBox Error.

I need to detect if something is wrong when running. I realize that there is Debug.LogError which we can detect an error. But Debug.LogError just print the message type by us to pointing what the object error is. What I need is to detect a global error like console and show error message from unity engine.

What I need may be something like :

```
void Update() {
       showMessageBox(isErrorDetect());
}

showMessageBox => is a function to show message box.
isErrorDetect => this will print an error if detect like a console.
```

If someone understand what I mean, then please, give me a solution.

Thank You

Comment: You can just log handled exceptions to a textbox UI element. Having an in-game message log is pretty common for games (when they're in debug mode).

Comment: I mean how to get the error log from console with script in c# ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So no one understand what i mean. But i got the solution my self.

We can use : **Application.logMessageReceived** that what i mean.

Script below will popup if there is an error when running the game at device. Not tested yet. But iam sure it work. It will help you when no error running in editor but got error when running at mobile.

I make it myself. Example :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ErrorHandlePopUp : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image PopUp;
    string error;

    void OnEnable() {
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
    }

    void OnDisable() {
        Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
    }

    void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type) {
        
        if (type == LogType.Error) {
            error = error + "\n" + logString;
            PopUp.gameObject.SetActive (true);
            PopUp.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Error";
            PopUp.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<Text> ().text = error;
        }   
    }

    public void Dismiss() {
        PopUp.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    }

}
```

Comment: This has been helpful! I would extend listening for other log types such as Exception and Assert.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the Debugger of the IDE. I assume you are writting your scripts in Monodeveloper or in Visual Studio. Both let you debug.

Even in the official website of Unity they recommend to use the debugger instead of a huge Debug.Log, which will be insane when your game gets complex.

You can read more about this here:

https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/monodevelops-debugger

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for giving another solution. But sometimes there is a case like when we need script A execute before script B but when in mobile script B is running before script A and this will make an error but in editor it is running okay. I realize that we can set the execute order script but when script A is a plugin asset we will not able to set the order like we want. This is happen to me when i contact the developer they give the solution to delay my script B before execute. So it is like let script A (plugin) finish execute. Even after it worked it editor it is not run smoothly in device.